# Marking a contact as closed/inactive

Tags: contacts

We have a school that is a contact organization and it has now closed how can I mark it as inactive/closed?

Comment: uuuuggh this is a long-standing pet peeve of mine re: CiviCRM - the inability to mark a contact as "inactive" without marking them "deceased".  I'm curious what other solutions people give - but IMO Civi contacts need a new checkbox.

Comment: @JonG we could reuse the 'is_deceased' column in the db for Orgs but present it with a different label. Might be a quick patch.

Comment: @Coleman not a bad idea in this particular case.  I think there's a case to be made for a new field, which I'll take to ~dev - I've refrained making the case because I haven't wanted to take on the work necessary to implement it.

Comment: I did not even see a deceased option for an organization only saw it for people.

Comment: @JonG, Coleman Sometimes you want to mark individuals as inactive so a separate field at the contact level would be good.  We've handled it with custom fields but something with more inbuilt semantics like is_deceased would be preferable.

Comment: @YoniYares You're right - we're discussing more what COULD be than what IS.  Coleman thinks it could be a quick fix; I'm not 100% convinced.  I'll try to talk to some other folks about what it would take to add this.

Comment: In general, I am not a fan of tags, but in this case a tag works well; Also recommend marking as do not mail/email/contact.

Comment: The question is what "inactive" means in your context. Why would you need a special field for that? Is it not evident from the lack of certain relationships of memberships? If there is a contact without memberships, isn't it then obvious that this member is "inactive"?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to use a custom field for that. And make sure when you search for contacts you search for active contacts.